# There are many HTTP request in my jmx file ,I want to hit one HTTP request just one time irrespective of no of threads set for all

Tags: jmeter

My case is-
I have to login in a website and then have to fecth a data.
For that I have created one thread group and created two HTTP request , one for login and one to fetch data.
But I want login HTTP request to HIt one time and data fetching to hit for many Virtual users.
But There is one common thread group for both.
Please help How I can sort out this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run all requests after login in parallel, you may use [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md) plugin:

1. Install `JMeter Plugin Manager`: Download [plugins-manager.jar](https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/) and put it into `lib/ext` directory, then restart JMeter.
2. Open menu Options -> Plugins Manager
3. Install `Parallel Controller & Sampler` plugin.
4. Add the `Parallel Controller` to the Test Plan: Right click on Thread Group -> Add -> Logic Controller -> bzm - Parallel Controller
5. Add your request samplers inside Parallel Controller.

Choose your [Thread Group](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/guide-jmeter-thread-groups/) and set the number of threads (users) and loop count.

> Each thread will execute the test plan in its entirety and completely independently of other test threads. Multiple threads are used to simulate concurrent connections to your server application.

So, if you want to run login sampler just once, set:

- `Number of Threads (users)` to 1
- `Loop Count` to 1

[image: Number of Threads (users)]

There are also different types of Thread Groups. Check [official documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) for more information

Answer (score 0):

JMeter threads (virtual users) are totally independent from each other, they use [Thread Local Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) pattern for storing session information and variables therefore if you login with one user - it will be able to fetch the data, the second user will not be able to fetch the data if he isn't logged in.

If you're absolutely sure that you want to share the same login session across multiple virtual users and perform login only once consider the following test setup:

1. [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) with 1 virtual user and 1 loop to perform login
2. [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) to store the session information (i.e. Cookies) and pass it to the normal Thread Group
3. Normal [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with as many users as you need using the data from the setUp Thread Group

Check out [SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx) test plan for reference implementation.